# scala test play parse.mulipartFormData

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

Attempting to test a play function that parses a multipartFormData

```
def requestBulkSiteSbcActionConfirm = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { request => ....
```

The test i've created is

```
      val temporartyFile = TemporaryFile("test")
  val filePart = FilePart("key: String", "test.csv", None, temporartyFile)
  val multipartFormData: MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile] = MultipartFormData(Map(),Seq(filePart), Seq())
  val request: Request[AnyContentAsMultipartFormData] = FakeRequest().withHeaders(("Content-Type"->"multipart/form-data")).withMultipartFormDataBody(multipartFormData)
  val pw = new PrintWriter(filePart.ref.file)
  pw.write(s"$TestSiteId_1, ${AdLeft.id}, on\n")
  pw.write(s"$TestSiteId_2, ${AdRight.id}, off\n")
  pw.close()
  val acc: Accumulator[ByteString, Result] = controller.requestBulkSiteSbcActionConfirm().apply(request)
```

which exceptions

```
- valid file sbc command list *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
[info]   at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347) 
[info]   at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$$anonfun$multipartFormData$1.apply(ContentTypes.scala:657)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$$anonfun$multipartFormData$1.apply(ContentTypes.scala:656)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.BodyParser$$anon$8.apply(Action.scala:258)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.BodyParser$$anon$8.apply(Action.scala:257)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.Action$class.apply(Action.scala:103)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:455)
[info]   at controllers.SbcConfigControllerTest$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SbcConfigControllerTest.scala:64)
[info]   at controllers.SbcConfigControllerTest$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SbcConfigControllerTest.scala:55)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some internal parts of Play still uses a global state for execution, it seems you just hit one: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/ContentTypes.scala#L657

This should change with play 2.6 but meanwhile you should start an application in your test to make it work

Comment: yeah saw that also but i'm not sure how to start an application in my test?

Comment: Play has some helpers to use an application while testing like the trait `OneAppPerSuite`. I recommend that you take a look at the examples in the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest#Creating-Application-instances-for-testing)